# How to speed up an excel macro that runs in a shared file?

Tags: excel, vba, performance, shared-libraries

I have put together a code for copying bits and pieces of info from a number of excel files into one large master file. However, the master file is stored on a shared drive which is almost full. Plus the file name (and the folder name in which the file can be found) is changing on a monthly basis. I was using the "*" wildcard at the end of both the path and the file name. Since there are a couple of subfolders, it takes minutes for the algorithm to run through and the worksheet is freezing for a few seconds as well, so actually I am not saving any time, which was the original purpose. Maybe do you have any idea how to speed things up a little? Thank you in advance!

You can find the code below

```
Sub OVtablecopy3()

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Copy

    Dim newest As Date
    Dim current As Date
    Dim right_file As String
    Dim rot_cnt As Integer
    rot_cnt = 1

    Dim my_path As String
    Dim file_name As String
    my_path = "\\mypath\which\Icouldnotwritefully\sinceitsconfidential\butyouget\theidea\maybe\*\"
    file_name = Dir("My_monthly changing_filename*.xlsx")

    Do While file_name <> vbNullString
        If rot_cnt = 1 Then
            newest = FileDateTime(file_name)
        End If
        If rot_cnt >= 1 Then
            current = FileDateTime(file_name)
        End If
        If DateSerial(Year(current), Month(current), Day(current)) >= _
                                                                   DateSerial(Year(newest), Month(newest), Day(newest)) Then
            newest = FileDateTime(file_name)
            right_file = file_name
        End If
        file_name = Dir()
        rot_cnt = rot_cnt + 1
    Loop

    Workbooks.Open (right_file)

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: I believe you can explicitly compare those dates without the `DateSerial(Year(...))`

Comment: Are you able to put breakpoints in and make sure that browsing the folders is actually the longest part? I'm betting that as the drive has filled up the `.Open()` and `.Paste` are what actually take the most time. That said, I don't see much to functionally improve the macro. Best idea I have is setting up a blacklist for large folders you know wont have anything in them

Comment: Do you try to suggest that looping between all subfolders takes long time? I do not think so... Put a break point on the line  `Workbooks.Open (right_file)` and see after how many seconds it will be highlighted. Your code will reach that line in less of a second. But, in case of a (big) shared file, the speed of workbook processing can be extremely low. Such an workbook records all changes made by all users and its size increases a lot. I used to un-share followed by sharing again from time to time in order to keep it at a reasonable size. A big size shared workbook can take time to be loaded

Comment: Maybe it would be faster to copy the master book to your computer, open it and paste your content, then replace the now old version on the drive?

Comment: I tried the break point and actually it took 2-3 seconds at max.

Comment: Also copying the master file to my PC can be a good idea. At first I tested the macro on files I stored on my desktop and it was so smooth, so I know it works. However I am not the only one who is working with that file. Probably it is not a huge effort for anybody to download the file and upload it again. Still my aim was to make this copy-paste process as fast as possible.  Thank you for the tips. :)

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 you wrote: I believe you can explicitly compare those dates without the DateSerial(Year(...)) - Maybe can you help me how can I do that? I am not really a macro specialist tbh

Comment: `If current > newest Then ...` :)

Comment: Ah, yeah, with it being a shared file I can see why this would be an issue. Not sure there's a reasonable workaround

Comment: I have also read on some forums that copy and paste command is slowing down the macro (what a pity that I compiled the whole thing to makes this process faster :D) They advised that this formula should be used for example "Range("A1:Z100").value = Range("A101:Z200").value" - however, the data range I need copy is different in every separate excel. Maybe is there a way to apply the above line to data ranges of unknown length?

Comment: It's possible that it could help and is reasonable to implement. I think that would warrant being posted as a different question, though. Don't forget to make an attempt first because you already have most of the necessary code - it will just need to rearranged and slightly modified